# Netbeans (ant) rename jar file with apps version

Tags: xml, netbeans, ant

**What i want :**

Generate jar file with apps version in name, Ex : **MyApps-1.3_Beta.jar**

In my src folder , i have a file named "version.properties" which contain :

> ...
>   **apps=MyApps**
>   **apps.version=1.3_Beta**
>   ...

i need to change value of property **"dist.jar"** to something like this :

> **dist/${apps}-${apps.version}.jar**

**build.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyApps" default="default" basedir=".">
  <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project MyApps.</description>
  <target name="-pre-init">
      <property file="${src.dir}\MyApps\version.properties"/>
      <property name="dist.jar" value="dist/${apps}-${apps.version}.jar" />
   </target>
  <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
  <import file="nbproject/profiler-build-impl.xml"/>
  <echo level="info">${dist.jar} instead of dist/${apps}-${apps.version}.jar</echo>
</project>
```

**Echo output :**

> **dist/${apps}-${apps.version}.jar** instead of **dist/MyApps-1.3_Beta.jar**

The problem is that ${...} is not interpreted, and i don't know why.

I can't modify **"build-impl.xml"** because it can be regenerate by Netbeans (When i modify this file (all ${dist.jar}), it works but it's not a good solution).

**How can i change "dist.jar" property ?**

**NB**: it's not a problem if for change **"dist.jar"** I'm not using **"project.properties"**, project name and apps name can be different, but for **"dist"** folder it will be better to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not reading the properties file you want.  Run Ant with the `-verbose` arg and you may see something like:

```
[property] Loading src\MyApps\version.properties
[property] Unable to find property file: src\MyApps\version.properties
```

(In the text you say the properties file is in the `src` directory, but the buildfile is looking for it in src\MyApps.)